# How to solve this error? Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default

Tags: updates

Hello everyone I'm using ubuntu 22.04 on a dual boot system with windows, I recently updated from 21.04.

If it helps this is the result from running `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I was trying to install KiCAD, and when I ran `sudo apt-get update` I get the below error:

```
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease           
Hit:5 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease             
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease              
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu impish InRelease            
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kicad/kicad-6.0-releases/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kicad/kicad-6.0-releases/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm pretty new to Linux and Ubuntu so some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you have Impish repositories still enabled? You are on 22.04 and Impish is dead.  You should not have any Impish references in your PPAs or in your sources.list anymore.

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere: either you are using 21.10 since "impish" is 21.10 in your question or you messed up your sources.  I assume you need to fix your sources ;)

Comment: @ThomasWard yeah I'm not sure about that when I installed 22.04 Impish probably, I still have the drivers and installation medium for 'Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri'. Do I just remove that on Software and Updates

Comment: @Rinzwind I probably did haha. Should I just reinstall 22.04 or is there a different way?

Comment: Whether you release-upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 or clean-install 22.04 is entirely up to you. There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches. If you want to learn, try both.